# jQuery UI: Click event is being triggered on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, resizable

I am using jQuery Ui resizable on an element. But resizing event is triggering click event of the element itself and click event of its parent. I have tried using `event.stopPropagation()` but it doesn't work apparently.

Here's a simple form of my html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child ui-resizable">
        ...
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my js looks like this:

```
$('.parent').on('click',function(){
   openModal();
});

$('.child').on('click',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation(); // To Prevent the child triggering parent click event.
    openSecondModal();
});

$('.ui-resizable').resizable({
    ghost: true,
    grid: 24,
    handles: "s",
    resize: function (event, ui) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    },
    start: function (event, ui) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    },

})
```

Dragging the handler is triggering the click event.
Is there a way to prevent click event from action?

Comment: @Stavm Do you mean setting "stopPropagation()" to click event of ".ui-resizable"? I did, and still click events are being triggered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel click after resizable events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709220/how-to-cancel-click-after-resizable-events)

Comment: @Stavm I have checked that before, but answers didn't solve my problem. Actually my layout and nesting elements are more complicated, so that the answers to that question doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
$('.parent').on('click',function(e){
   if(e.target !== e.currentTarget) return;
   openModal();
});
```